# Не получается запустить команду zip из скрипта

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip, ziparchive

У меня не работает пример программы из книжки.

```
import os 
import time

source = ['"C:\\My Documents"', 'C:\\Code'] 

target_dir = 'C:\\Backup'

target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

zip_command = "zip  -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))

print(zip_command) 
if os.system(zip_command) == 0: 
    print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target) 
else:
    print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')
```

Вывод всегда один и тот же:

> ```
> zip  -qr C:\Backup\20180914031536.zip "C:\My Documents" C:\Code
> Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ
> ```

только при указании не существующих директорий вывод немного меняется.

Не пойму в чем проблема. `C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin` к системной переменной окружения `PATH` я вроде добавил, всё вроде должно работать.

Windows 10, Python 3.6

```
C:\Users\Frost>zip -qr C:\Backup\20180917121916 . -i .zip C:\My Documents C:\Code

zip I/O error: No such file or directory

zip error: Could not create output file (C:/Backup/20180917121916.zip)
-@Alex
```

Comment: При выполнении команды в консоле выдает  "zip" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Comment: Вся проблема в адресе. Верный адрес C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin а не C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin. Но теперь появилась ошибка: zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -qr C:\Backup\20180914031536.zip . -i C:\My Documents C:\Code)

Comment: zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))  Архив не создаётся. Вывод после использования скрипта:  zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -qr C:\Backup\20180914070607 . -i .zip C:\My Documents C:\Code)
Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ @Alex

Comment: 1. Ничего не изменилось 2.` zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -qr C:\Backup\20180914074828.zip . -i C:\My Documents)
Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ` (с измененным адресом ) 3. `zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -qr C:\Backup\20180914074859 . -i .zip C:\My Documents C:\Code)
Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ` (старый вариант) @Alex

Comment: Не нужно писать дополнительную информацию в комментариях, они не для этого. Добавьте все, что считаете нужным в сам вопрос, используя кнопку "Править" под ним.

Answer (score 2):

Раз код не выпадает в исключение - значит, утилита zip отрабатывает корректно. Это уже хорошо.

Попробуй прямо в системе открыть консоль (cmd) и в ней выполнить получившуюся команду (`zip  -qr C:\Backup\20180914031536.zip "C:\My Documents" C:\Code`). Возможно, zip выведет сообщение об ошибке, по которому можно будет понять, что же ему не понравилось)

**UPD.**: Судя по ошибке "не является внутренней или внешней командой" - я был неправ, утилита ZIP всё-таки не отрабатывает: скорее всего, интерпретатор просто не может её найти. Варианта решения я вижу два:

1. Разобраться, где лежит исполняемый файл zip.exe, и добавить этот каталог в PATH. После этого команда в консоли (cmd) должна начать выполняться - а после этого должна заработать и программа на Python.
   Кстати, тут ещё момент: после изменения PATH интерпретатор лучше перезапустить (прямо закрыть окно и запустить заново), а то переменные среды могут не обновиться.
2. (*грязный хак*) Просто прописать в `zip_command` вместо `zip` полный путь к архиватору (скажем, `C:\\Program Files\\GnuWin32\\bin\\zip.exe`).

Если оставить только первый файл - архив создаётся? Как выглядит `zip_command`?

1. Если заменить source = `['"C:\\My Documents"', 'C:\\Code']` на `source = ['"C:\\My Documents"']` - какой будет результат?
2. Перед сообщением "Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ" скрипт должен печатать команду, которая будет выполнена. В изначальном примере скрипт печатал следующее: `zip  -qr C:\Backup\20180914031536.zip "C:\My Documents" C:\Code`.
   Как выглядит эта строка сейчас?

Answer (score 0):

target_dir = 'C:\Backup'
Вам необходимо ЗАРАНЕЕ создать данную директорию.

Answer (score 0):

Все легче чем ты думаешь:
1) проверь если в в C:\GnuWin32\bin\zip.exe , если ты там сам файл zip.exe. 
Я сам с этой проблемой столкнулся и его не было там. Далее ;

2) в строке `zip_command = "zip  -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))`

исправь на : `zip_command = 'zip -r {0} {1}'.format(target, ' '.join(source))`;

3)Посмотри пути к файлу и путь к папке куда идет backup. Вот как у меня пути выглядят

```
source = ['C:\\Users\\nsmex\\Desktop\\backup']

target_dir = 'C:\\Users\\nsmex\\Desktop\\test'
```

Answer (score 0):

создай целевую папку C:\Backup. она у тебя не создана или, если создана, укажи путь  к ней

Comment: также создайте на диску С папки:  My Documents  и  Code

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow на русском! Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на две вещи. Во-первых, на то, что аналогичный ответ уже был дан год назад. М стараемся не дублировать однотипные ответы. Во-вторых, вы можете не дописывать комментарий, а дополнить ответ, нажав "править" под ответом.