# Резервное копирование ненужных файлов (короткий код)

Tags: python, резервное-копирование, копирование

Обучаюсь по книге A Byte of Python,и там нужно создать программу для резервной копии.Я все написал,все работает!
Однако,когда создается копия,дублируются файлы из папки самой программы.

```
import os
import time

source = ['"E:\\Reserve file"']

backup = 'E:\\Backup'

target = backup + os.sep + time.strftime('%c') + '.7z'

zip_command = "7z a -bt {0} {1}".format(backup, ' '.join(source))


print(zip_command)

if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target)
else:
    print('Создание резервной копии не удалось')
```

[image: Файлы,которые копируются]

[image: Файлы,которые содержатся вместе с программой]

Comment: На первой фотографии файлы,которые копируются.
На второй,расположение программы.

Comment: Это проклятая задача [спрашивалась](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/978302/python-%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0/978317#978317) уже сто раз.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не получается запустить команду zip из скрипта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/881138/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%83-zip-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0):

Все,решил!
Нужно в переменной (в моем случае zip_command) добавить команду -tzip

`zip_command = "7z a -bt -tzip {0} {1}".format(backup, ' '.join(source))`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/881138/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%83-zip-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0/881142#881142